# Rx groupby until condition changed

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm stuck with rx and a specific query.
The problem:

> Many single update operations are produced by continuous stream. The operations can be insert or delete. I want to buffer those streams and perform few operations at the time, but it is really important to preserve the order. Additionally, operations should be buffered and done in sequences every X seconds

Example:

In:

```
insert-insert-insert-delete-delete-insert-delete-delete-delete-delete
```

Out:

```
insert(3)-delete(2)-insert(1)-delete(4)
```

I wrote a simple application to test it, and it works more or less as I would but it doesn't respect the order of incoming insert/delete

```
namespace RxTests
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

internal class Program
{
    private static readonly Random Random = new Random();

    private static readonly CancellationTokenSource ProducerStopped = new CancellationTokenSource();

    private static readonly ISubject<UpdateOperation> operations = new Subject<UpdateOperation>();

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting production");
        var producerScheduler = new EventLoopScheduler();
        var consumerScheduler = new EventLoopScheduler();
        var producer =
            Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
                      .SubscribeOn(producerScheduler)
                      .Subscribe(Produce, WriteProductionCompleted);
        var consumer =
            operations.ObserveOn(producerScheduler)
                      .GroupBy(operation => operation.Delete)
                      .SelectMany(observable => observable.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8), 50))
                      .SubscribeOn(consumerScheduler)
                      .Subscribe(WriteUpdateOperations);
        Console.WriteLine("Type any key to stop");
        Console.ReadKey();
        consumer.Dispose();
        producer.Dispose();
    }

    private static void Produce(long time)
    {
        var delete = Random.NextDouble() < 0.5;
        Console.WriteLine("Produce {0}, {1} at {2}", time + 1, delete, time);
        var idString = (time + 1).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var id = time + 1;
        operations.OnNext(
            new UpdateOperation(id, delete, idString, time.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
    }

    private static void WriteProductionCompleted()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Production completed");
        ProducerStopped.Cancel();
    }

    private static void WriteUpdateOperation(UpdateOperation updateOperation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Consuming {0}", updateOperation);
    }

    private static void WriteUpdateOperations(IList<UpdateOperation> updateOperation)
    {
        foreach (var operation in updateOperation)
        {
            WriteUpdateOperation(operation);
        }
    }

    private class UpdateOperation
    {
        public UpdateOperation(long id, bool delete, params string[] changes)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Delete = delete;
            this.Changes = new List<string>(changes ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>());
        }

        public bool Delete { get; set; }

        public long Id { get; private set; }

        public IList<string> Changes { get; private set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("{UpdateOperation ");
            stringBuilder.AppendFormat("Id: {0}, Delete: {1}, Changes: [", this.Id, this.Delete);
            if (this.Changes.Count > 0)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(this.Changes.First());
                foreach (var change in this.Changes.Skip(1))
                {
                    stringBuilder.AppendFormat(", {0}", change);
                }
            }

            stringBuilder.Append("]}");
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

}

can anybody help me with the right query?

Thanks

**UPDATE 08.03.13 (Suggestions by JerKimball)**

The following lines are small changes/additions to JerKimball's code to print the results:

```
using(query.Subscribe(Print))
{
    Console.ReadLine();
    producer.Dispose();        
}
```

Using the following Print methods:

```
private static void Print(IObservable<IList<Operation>> operations)
{
    operations.Subscribe(Print);
}

private static void Print(IList<Operation> operations)
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("[");
    if (operations.Count > 0)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append(operations.First());
        foreach (var item in operations.Skip(1))
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendFormat(", {0}", item);
        }
    }

    stringBuilder.Append("]");
    Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder);
 }
```

and the following to string for the Operation:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0}:{1}", this.Type, this.Seq);
}
```

Order is preserved, but:

- I'm not sure about subscribing within another subscription: is it correct (that's a question I have since long time ago and was never clear to me)?
- I always have no more than two elements on each list (even if the stream produces more than two consecutive values with the same Type)

Comment: `I'm not sure about subscribing within another subscription: is it correct` <- what do you mean by this? Where is this happening? (edit) Oh, I see - in your `Print`...yeah, you don't want to do this, if only because you are now leaking an `IDisposable`

Comment: `Subscribe` has an overload that takes an `Action<T>` - use that; that's why I use `Console.WriteLine` in my example. If you change the signature of `Print` to take `IList<Operation>`, you can just `using(query.Subscribe(Print))`

Comment: From the Select I get an IObservable<IObservable<IList<Operation>>>, that's why I used the first Print(IObservable<IList<Operation>> operations). So I will wrap again the second operations.Subscribe(Print) within a using

Comment: if I write "using(operations.Subscribe(Print))" nothing is displayed.
And anyway there is the issue with the max of two operations for each write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try a new approach (hence new answer):

First, let's define an extension method that will "collapse" lists of items based on a key while retaining order:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static IEnumerable<List<T>> ToRuns<T, TKey>(
            this IEnumerable<T> source, 
            Func<T, TKey> keySelector) 
    {
        using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator()) 
        {
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                yield break;

            var currentSet = new List<T>();

            // inspect the first item
            var lastKey = keySelector(enumerator.Current);
            currentSet.Add(enumerator.Current);

            while (enumerator.MoveNext()) 
            {
                var newKey = keySelector(enumerator.Current);
                if (!Equals(newKey, lastKey)) 
                {
                    // A difference == new run; return what we've got thus far
                    yield return currentSet;
                    lastKey = newKey;
                    currentSet = new List<T>();
                }
                currentSet.Add(enumerator.Current);
            }

            // Return the last run.
            yield return currentSet;

            // and clean up
            currentSet = new List<T>();
            lastKey = default(TKey);
        }
    }
}
```

Fairly straightforward - given an `IEnumerable<T>`, will yield back a `List<List<T>>` where each sublist will have the same key.

Now, to feed it and use it:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var fakeSource = new Subject<Operation>();
var producer = Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000))
    .Subscribe(i => 
        {
            var op = new Operation();
            op.Type = rnd.NextDouble() < 0.5 ? "insert" : "delete";
            fakeSource.OnNext(op);
        });    

var singleSource = fakeSource
    .Publish().RefCount();

var query = singleSource
    // change this value to alter your "look at" time window
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))    
    .Select(buff => buff.ToRuns(op => op.Type).Where(run => run.Count > 0));

using(query.Subscribe(batch => 
{
    foreach(var item in batch)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}({1})", item.First().Type, item.Count);
    }
}))
{
    Console.ReadLine();
    producer.Dispose();     
}
```

Give that a whirl - here's what I see in a typical run:

```
insert(4)
delete(2)
insert(1)
delete(1)
insert(1)
insert(1)
delete(1)
insert(1)
delete(2)
delete(2)
insert(2)
delete(1)
insert(1)
delete(2)
insert(2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
That does exactly what I need. I'll give you the very well deserved bounty!

Answer (score 4):

Methinks you can get what you're after with a mix of `GroupByUntil`, `DistinctUntilChanged`, and `Buffer`:

This requires a bit of tweaking to fit your example code, but the query (and concept) *should* hold:

(edit: doh - missed a bit there...)

```
void Main()
{
    var rnd = new Random();
    var fakeSource = new Subject<Operation>();
    var producer = Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000))
        .Subscribe(i => 
            {
                var op = new Operation();
                op.Type = rnd.NextDouble() < 0.5 ? "insert" : "delete";
                fakeSource.OnNext(op);
            });    
    var singleSource = fakeSource.Publish().RefCount();

    var query = singleSource
        // We want to groupby until we see a change in the source
        .GroupByUntil(
               i => i.Type, 
               grp => singleSource.DistinctUntilChanged(op => op.Type))
        // then buffer up those observed events in the groupby window
        .Select(grp => grp.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8), 50));

    using(query.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine))
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
        producer.Dispose();        
    }
}

public class Operation { 
    private static int _cnt = 0;
    public Operation() { Seq = _cnt++; }
    public int Seq {get; set;}
    public string Type {get; set;}    
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks, but it doesn't give me the expected output.
I actually think that GroupBy is not right for my needs, because I need more to switch between two streams.
Could you verify the output of your solution? Thanks

Comment: @fra Hah - missed a part...*sigh* I'll edit...ok, try the updated version?

Comment: thank you very much, we're almost there. There are still a couple of doubts and issues, please check my updated question

Comment: Why not just use the `.Buffer()` [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229432(v=vs.103).aspx) that takes a "closing" stream in conjunction with `.DistinctUntilChanged()`?

Comment: The problem with using DistinctUntilChanged as a trigger for Buffer/Window is that when the signal changes (i.e., a new type), it's already made it into the now closing buffer, so it's a-a-a-b, for example; however, if you did the buffering on a once-removed stream (time = t + 1), that might work. There's a potentially easier way, however - check my other answer.